# NextJS having links in the _document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

Working on a application which uses NextJS. Having the following problem. When I have a `_document` file like this:

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Header from '../components/header/header';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Header />   // Header is custom component
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

And my Header component is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';

class navigationMobile extends Component {    

    render() {
        return (
            <nav>
                <Link href="/auth"><a>Auth</a></Link>
            </nav>
        );
    }


}

export default withRouter(navigationMobile);
```

Because this link is placed outside of the file it will reload the page for some reason. This will lose the application state and ruin UX and kind off defeats the purpose of implementing something with a SPA.

When I place the Header component in a page itself the routing works fine. The problem however is that I would have to put this component in every page.

### Question:

Is there a way to not reload the page and still have the header component only in one place of the application?

Comment: Why not import `<Header/>` in pages like in [docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/using-router/pages/index.js)? `<Link />` with `<a>` w/o href inside, `withRouter` IMHO to many things mixed. Shouldn't it be `<Link/>` OR `withRouter` with `<a/>` using props from HOC?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `_app.js`. This is the correct place where to put a custom layout.
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master#custom-app

Answer (score 0):

The entry point in Next.js is the _app.js, every page in the pages folder is rendered from here. Since we want our Header to appear on all pages, this is the best place to get it done. But for readability, let's create a new component, say `Layout` and import it into `_app.js`. We render it as shown below. And so, `<Component />` gets passed as children prop, we can use in the Layout component later:

`_app.js`

```
import Layout from 'components/Layout'


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp
```

`components/Layout.js`

```
import Header from './Header' // Make sure to import from the right location

const Layout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            {children} // This is the page meant to be rendered (passed from _app.js)
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

This way, we can have our Header (or footer or any other shared component) on every page without the page reloading.

Extra:
In our `Layout.js` we could check which page is being rendered by doing `{children.type.name}`. Using this, we can render the shared component (Header in this case) conditionally if we don't want it to appear on all pages.